# Is there a way to change a Python object's byte representation at run-time?

Tags: python, byte

The goal is to simulate a high-radiation environment.

Normally, code like the following:

```
a = 5
print(a)
print(a)
```

would print:

```
5
5
```

I want to be able to change the underlying byte representation of `a` randomly during runtime (according to some predefined function that takes a seed). In that case, the following code:

```
a = RandomlyChangingInteger(5)
print(a)
print(a)
```

could result in:

```
4
2
```

One way this can be done for languages like C and C++ is to insert extra instructions that could potentially modify `a`, before every usage of `a` in the compiled code.
Something like [BITFLIPS](https://www.techbriefs.com/component/content/article/tb/supplements/stb/briefs/3185) (which uses valgrind) is what I'm thinking about.

Is this even possible in Python?

Comment: I am well-versed with Python's random number generation capabilities. The question is about the byte-representation of objects. I'm not only interested in integers. Further, I'm not calling any *resample()* function in the (user-facing) code itself.

Comment: You... *want* to randomly corrupt your memory. Am I understanding this correctly? What are you even trying to do this for? Is your program going to run in a high-radiation environment?

Comment: Yes, you can insert appropriate code in Python, just as with other general-purpose languages.  However, your desired effect is not yet clear.

Comment: Yes, correct! I want to simulate radiation effects. See the link to BITFLIPS posted!

Comment: Just a link as to how to get started would be helpful. I don't understand the downvotes, I thought the question was well-posed. Let me know if I should change something.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, sort of. The built-in `int` is immutable, therefore you cannot modify its value. You can, however, create a custom class that emulates an `int`:

```
import random


class RandomlyChangingInteger(object):
    def __int__(self):
        return random.randint(0, 10)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__int__())
```

then

```
a = RandomlyChangingInteger()
print(a)
print(a)
```

should print something like

```
4
5
```

Note that you can't use this class to do math as it stands. You must implement other `int` methods (such as `__add__`, `__mul__`, etc) first.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that I would have to subclass this for every single type of object that I want to modify (and as you point out, I would also have to implement these other methods). I was wondering if modifying the byte-level representation of objects would allow me to bypass all of this. I'm willing to make a *modified* compiler/interpreter for this purpose, too. (So the modifying code doesn't need to be in Python itself).

Comment: This does randomly fiddle with the object's value, but it isn't a very accurate simulation of radiation effects. A typical Python int is about 80% metadata (and that's not even counting the pointers *to* the int); radiation is more likely to corrupt stuff like type pointers and refcounts than it is to change a valid int value to another int value. (Also there's stuff like constant folding and the small int cache, which this doesn't interact with.)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to simulate radiation-induced bitflips, but your expectations of what that would do are way off target. Radiation effects are much more likely to crash a Python program than they are to change an object's value to another valid value. This makes simulating radiation effects not very useful.

The CPython implementation relies on so many pointers and so much indirection that after a few bit flips in your data, at least one of them is almost certain to hit something that causes a crash. Perhaps corrupting an object's type pointer, causing a bad memory access the next time you try to do almost anything with the object, or perhaps corrupting a reference count, causing an object to be freed while still in use. Maybe corrupting the length of an int (Python ints are variable-width), causing Python to try to read past the end of the allocation.

Where a C array of ints might just be a giant block of numerical data, where random bit corruption could be detected or managed, a Python list of ints is mostly pointers and other metadata.

If you really want to simulate random bit flips, the best way to go would likely be to rebuild CPython with a tool like the BITFLIPS thing you linked.

Comment: I have read that numpy arrays used fixed-size datatypes (like 32-bit integers), and are stored contiguously in memory (like a C array). Do you think numpy arrays could be modified for something like this?

Comment: Thanks, still! This is all very interesting.

Comment: @Ameya: With large NumPy arrays, the chances of a bitflip corrupting data instead of metadata grow a lot, but the best way to do what you want with a NumPy array would still be to work at C level, perhaps with that BITFLIPS thing you linked.

Comment: Yes, BITFLIPS allows you to specify which *regions* of memory you are allowing to be modified. I'm thinking of the case where you only expose the 'data' and not the 'pointers' as you point out.